# creating and sorting a dynamic list of lists

Tags: python

This is a more challenging problem I'm trying to solve. I know that I can create a list of empty lists `sortedList =[[],[],[]]` and in this case sortedList at index 0 has an empty list, same at index 1 and 2.

I am tasked with gathering input from a user and creating a list of words and stopping when the user types stop. I managed this well enough by doing:

```
def wordList():
unsortedList=[]
promptUser=""   
while promptUser !="stop":

    promptUser = input("Type words, one at a time. When you are done, type stop: ")
    unsortedList.append(promptUser)
    if promptUser =="stop":
        unsortedList.pop(-1)


#print(wordList)
wordList()
```

I had to use sloppy code to not include the word stop using the pop method. Not pretty but it works. My real issue is this. I need a while or for loop to go through the unsortedList and look at every word and evaluate it for the count of each item in the list.

Conceptually I'm okay here, but the challenge is that based on the assessment of each item in the unsortedList, I should create a sortedList that takes all user input grouped by length and creates a new list for each length group so a list of lists dynamically created based on user input, and grouped based on the number of characters.

So I know that a list of lists will follow the index order, the first list will be index 0 and so on. I also understand that it is possible to go through the unsortedList and get a character count of each item in the list. In theory with that information, I could take all words of length n and insert them into a sublist, then find all the words with a different length n and put them in a sublist.

High level my unsortedList will contain various words that can be sorted based on character length. I can assume no word will exceed 10 characters, but empty strings are possible.

Go through this unsortedList and create a sortedList that itself contains sublists holding groupings based on all of the items from the unsortedList so perhaps the returned sortedList might have:
`[[],[a,n,t],[red,eye],[toad,roar,flap],[closer,smarter,faster]]`

I understand the individual logical steps, but the actual iteration through the unsortedlist, using the evaluations to then create a sortedList with the individual grouped sublists is just beyond me. I learn well by looking at complete code examples, but I just can't find anything here that does this to study so any help is appreciated. Sorry for the lengthy post.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently this is a wall of text with no clear question.

Comment: Am i right, that you are asking, how to turn `unsortedList` into list of lists, where each list contains only values of equal length?

Comment: Thank you to everybody who asked questions, or provided answers. I apologize for the poor structure and lack of clarity in my very long question. All input and critiques were invaluable, and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question right, you want to turn `unsorted_list` into list of lists, where each list contains only values of equal length. This can be achieved like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

unsorted_list = ['a', 'n', 't', 'red', 'eye', 'toad', 'roar', 'flap']

def group_strings_by_length(lst):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)

    for s in lst:
        grouped[len(s)].append(s)
    return list(grouped.values())

grouped_strings = group_strings_by_length(unsorted_list)  
print(grouped_strings)  #[['a', 'n', 't'], ['red', 'eye'], ['toad', 'roar', 'flap']]
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will find the longest letter in your list, create another list which is that long and sort every word into its bucket. I also fixed your read in loop a bit, no need for a weird way of checking

```
def wordList():
    unsortedList=[]
    promptUser=input("Type words, one at a time. When you are done, type stop: ")  

    while promptUser !="stop":
        unsortedList.append(promptUser)
        promptUser = input("Type words, one at a time. When you are done, type stop: ")


    sortedList = []
    #will go from 0 up to and including length of longest letter in your list 
    for x in range(0,max([len(x) for x in unsortedList])+1):
        #Creates an empty entry
        sortedList.append([])
        #Goes through an unsorted list
        for s in unsortedList:
            #If length of a word is equal to x it adds it to its bucket
            if len(s) == x:
                sortedList[x].append(s)
    print(sortedList)


Input: ['a', 'eye', 'flap', 'n', 'red', 'roar', 't', 'toad']
Output: [[], ['a', 'n', 't'], [], ['eye', 'red'], ['flap', 'roar', 'toad']]
```